# Python Cannot Perform Absolute Imports

Tags: python

I'm having trouble importing using the scheme below.

```
-root_file.py
-package1
  -file1.py
-package2
  -file2.py
  -subfolder
   -file3.py
```

What I'm having trouble with is importing file2.py and file3.py into file1.py. I understand that python starts at the root directory when using absolute imports, so in file1.py:

```
import root_file
from package2 import file2
from package2.subfolder import file3
```

Shouldn't the above work? Do I need **init**.py files in each folder?

Comment: Is file1.py in package1? If so, the root directory will need to be the dir containing root_file.

Comment: Are you running file1.py directly (ex. python file1.py)? And from which folder are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is run file1.py from the root directory (e.g `python package1/file1.py`). What that does is set the root to that root directory, and the imports will work, being relative from there. If you run it as `python file1.py` from package1, then python can't find the other files because they are not based in the same directory.

Basically, Python can't traverse up the filesystem tree to find modules. So, when you run file1.py from package1, Python can't find the other modules because they are higher up on the tree. If, however, you run it from the root as package1/file1.py, then Python can 'see' those other modules and directories and can import the files.

Comment: Hi @2pichar, I tried running it like you said, but I still get a relative import error. I'm running it from the root folder but still to no avail. I also tried python -m package1/file1.py which also did not work. It might be important to note I am in vscode.

Comment: I had that problem in VSCode as well, but it was slightly different. I discovered that whatever the root directory of the workspace was, that was the root of the Python execution. So if I was using a launch configuration to run a Python file, then it would run, but the root of the folder was the workspace root.

Comment: Try changing the root of the workspace to wherever root_file.py is, and executing from there, and if that doesn't work then you can just add that directory to the PYTHON_PATH environmental variable. (Or append the path to sys.path, which does the same thing)